# Login and upload file at website with python

Tags: python, cookies

I'm making a python script that should zip a file and upload it at a site. My problem is I can't figure out how to login into the site to then upload the file in question.

I've searched trough the web but can't make any of the solutions presented online to work, probably because I don't understand most of them (my knowledge of cookies is quite limited).

The site in question is [CurseForge](http://www.curseforge.com/). If anyone could point me into the right direction, it would be great.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+upload+to+web+site.  All of these are the same question.  Pick one, and close this is a duplicate, please.

Comment: this is about a very specific site that none of us use, this reeks of `too localized` not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this variant of httplib2 [http://gnu.gabrielfalcao.com/bolacha/#uploading-a-file](http://github.com/gabrielfalcao/bolacha/tree/master) , it has examples on that page. You can get the code from http://github.com/gabrielfalcao/bolacha/tree/master